# parsing using scanf in C

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, input, scanf

I am learning C for the first time.

I have a pointer to a string called goalie_stat (see below). How would i use scanf to parse the save percentage, which is 933 and then assign 933 to a variable and then finally print it?

```
char *goalie_stat = "PatRoy 2.28  933  35  12  165 199  4   5500"

char save_p = scanf("%[13-15]", goalie_stat);
printf("%s", save_p);
```

'933' are the 13th, 14th and 15th characters of the string, but i know that this is incorrect

Comment: To read from a string, use `sscanf`. `scanf` reads from `stdin`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `sscanf` for parsing strings, not `scanf`:

```
int num;
sscanf(goalie_stat, "%*s %*s %d", &num);
printf("%d", num);
```

should do the trick! `%*s` reads and discards the first word of `goalie_stat` and the second `%*s` reads and discards the next word(2.28).  `%d` then reads the third number and stores it in `num`.

You should also check the return value of `sscanf` to see if it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sscanf()`. Its utilisation is described here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm